# C# linq : using query syntax where to insert groupby

Tags: c#, linq, excel-interop

Don't know where to insert group by what I tried

```
var filteredResult1 = from s in employeelist
                      group s by s.Department into s
                      where s.totalscore > 0 && s.totalscore <  400
                      select s.employeeID;
```

With this code I got the error :

> Error 2   'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'totalscore' and no extension method 'totalscore' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My question is, how can I translate `select employeeID where totalscore > 0 && totalscore < 400 group by department from employeelist` into Linq statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: The question is more where to insert the `where`, i guess you want it before the `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your Linq is this order :

1. From
2. Where
3. GroupBy
4. Select

In your case you can do it like this :

```
var filteredResult1 = employeelist.Where(emp => emp.totalscore > 0 && emp.totalscore < 400)
    .GroupBy(emp => emp.Department)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(emp => emp.employeeID).ToList()).ToList();
```

With the query syntax :

```
var filteredResult2 = from emp in employeelist
                      where emp.totalscore > 0 && emp.totalscore < 400
                      group emp by emp.Department into grp
                      from emp in grp
                      select emp.employeeID;
```

**emp** represent an Employee object
**grp** represent a Group (a key and a list of Employee objects)

Comment: @Gerald This is a Linq query, just a fluent one. But I will try to make with the syntax in your question.

Comment: isn't this lamda syntax ? sorry newbie here.

Comment: @Gerald Is it, I never used this syntax for my Linq. The 2 syntax return the same but I personally prefered the lamda.

Comment: could you explain or link me to any article that explain about the emp and grp in the syntax pls.

Comment: @Gerald I added the Linq query syntax (without the .ToList()). The emp or grp are just variable name. emp is always an Employee object and grp is a Group (a key and a list of Employee)

Comment: sorry,i just get into linq recently so lamda is difficult for me to understand although it's the same.

Comment: could you please tell me why i don't need grp in this case.var filteredResult4 = from s in employeelist:
                                   where s.totalscore > 0 && s.totalscore < 400
                                   select s.totalscore;  could you please tell me why i don't need grp in this case.

Comment: @Gerald Simply because it will give you the list of totalscore that are between 0 and 400, it will not group by department.

Comment: how do i select first 5 that are between 0 and 400 group by department

Comment: @Gerald Take a look at the Microsoft doc for this question (or do a google research, it will be better). There is the method Take in Linq to do this.